# pop to TableViewController from Detail Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, segue

I have a `ViewController1` which can do a push segue into a `ViewController2`. This, in turn, can do a push segue into a `ViewController3`. I have a `UIBarButtonItem` in the `ViewController1` that can do a push segue into the `ViewController3`. However, when I press the back button in the `ViewController3`, I need it to pop to `ViewController2`.

How would I do this? Here's the code I tried:

```
ViewController2 *VC2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] init];
ViewController3 *VC3 = [[ViewController3 alloc] init];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:VC2 animated:NO];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:VC3 animated:YES];
```

Comment: If you're using segues, you shouldn't be calling pushViewController:animated: at all -- the segues do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Tried your solution, and seems to be working for me,
but, anyway.. if for any reason it doesn't work for you... try with this:

```
NSArray *array = self.navigationController.viewControllers;
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:[array arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:@[vc1,vc2]] animated:YES];
```

Comment: That worked; sort of. I am using Storyboards and Segues, so some things did not work as I they should. I did, however, find something that worked for me based on the code you gave me. Answer below. Thanks, @Camo

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I finally found, based on the answer from @Camo. I present `ViewController3` from `ViewController1` via. Segue. Then, in the `ViewController3` `viewDidLoad`, I put this code:

```
NSArray *array = self.navigationController.viewControllers;
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
id TVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VC2"];

[self.navigationController setViewControllers:[array arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:@[TVC, self]] animated:NO];
```